# Analytical approximation of probability of one beta-distributed var being greater than another?

Tags: beta-distribution, approximation

The answer to [What is the probability P(X > Y) given X ~ Be(a1, b1), and Y ~ Be(a2, b2), and X and Y are independent?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25290/what-is-the-probability-px-y-given-x-bea1-b1-and-y-bea2-b2-and-x) provides an analytical solution for this, but is there a less computationally intensive expression if one is willing to lose some precision?

Assume integer a and b, if that helps.

Comment: Numerical integration would be my first thought. Simulation would be my second. The numerical integration would probably involve trying to use quadrature based on Jacobi polynomials. Neither of those are analytical though.

Comment: Both use quite a lot of iterations. I considered using precomputed tables, and interpolating, but this would use too much memory with inaccurate results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [this](https://www.johndcook.com/fast_beta_inequality.pdf)  close-form approximation  approximation. The author claim it is 2 orders of magnitude faster to evaluate.

To abide by CV rules I will be citing key infos
from the intro of this very clear paper:

The key idea is that:

> The key idea in that paper is that
>
> $$P(X_B>Y_B)\approx P(X_N>Y_N)$$
>
> where $X_B$ and $Y_B$ are independent beta random variables and $X_N$
> and $Y_N$ are their normal approximations formed by moment matching.
> The author shows that these approximations are rather accurate, even
> for small values of $(a_1,b_1)$ and $(a_2,b_2)$. For example: when
> these parameters  take integer values between 1 and 10 inclusive, the
> average  absolute error is 0.006676.

Edit:updated link.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Fast and sufficiently accurate!

Comment: Unfortunately, that paper doesn't show anything: it only makes a claim.  The average absolute error is encouraging but not terribly useful, because the cases with $a_i\approx b_i$ are going to be well approximated by the Normal distribution.  The tough cases are the skewed ones with very different values of $(a_i,b_i)$ or with very small values of at least one parameter.

Comment: @whuber thanks for your comment. I was merely updating the dead link. I think the author studies in fact the range of values of $a_i$ and $b_i$ for which the normal approximation works. The author indeed points out the need for an alternative approach when $a_i$ is very different from $b_i$ but does not offer any.

Answer (score 1):

I'm uncertain if this is answering the question you are asking. But you may want to check out [Asymptotics of Evan Miller's Bayesian A/B formula](https://www.chrisstucchio.com/blog/2014/bayesian_asymptotics.html). What they effectively are solving for is P(Conversion Rate of A > Conversion Rate of B) given two Beta distributions.

Comment: Welcome to the site! You can improve this answer by expanding it, perhaps by giving a summary of the information at the link.